# bash converting every third column into row

Tags: linux, file-management

I have a input file as
input file:

```
a b c d e f g h
i j k l m n o p q r 
s t u v w x
```

and my output should be
output file:

```
a b c d
a b e f
a b g h
i j k l
i j m n
i j o p
i j q r
s t u v 
s t w x
```

Any command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F ' ' '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2) print $1" "$2" "$i" "$(i+1)}'
```

It's quite a basic loop through fields. Notes:

- If there are less than three fields then the whole line will be ignored. If you want it printed anyway, use this instead:

  ```
  awk -F ' ' '{if (NF<3) print; for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2) print $1" "$2" "$i" "$(i+1)}'
  ```
- An input line with 3, 5 or 7 fields (or any higher odd number) will generate its final output line with a trailing space as if (respectively) the 4th, 6th or 8th field was there in the input as an empty field.
- Single space as the field separator (`-F ' '`) is a special case that matches one or more spaces and/or tabs. If you want two consecutive spaces to be interpreted as two delimiters (with an empty field in between), use a regular expression that matches a single space: `-F '[ ]'`.
- You mentioned input and output *files*, so you probably want to use redirections:

  ```
  <input_file awk … >output_file
  ```

  where `awk …` represents the command of your choice.

Comment: It worked!!
Thank You. I also made a python script to do this task but awk seems to do it in one line